# What does 'relate' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The ordinary people **relate** to divinity and the sacred through the means provided by the religion.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to make it about something completely different; **especially** after somebody has already answered it. If you have a new question to ask, ask a new question.

Comment: And to answer your edited question: it has no literal meaning, but it is a very obvious metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Relate in this context means to identify with.

Meaning: Through religion, ordinary people can identify with the sacred and divinity.